# Plotting a circle that can move up and down the y-axis

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic

How can I create a circle for the equation

$\qquad x^2+(y-a)^2=9$

where $a$ is a parameter. I want to plot this curve with a slider $(a)$ in Cartesian coordinates (better with axes). If possible, can u guys draw $a x^2 + bx + c = 0$ in the same plane.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcSvW.jpg
`Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[{x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 9}, {x, -14, 14}, {y, -14, 14}, 
  Axes -> True], {a, -3, 3, 1}]`

Comment: What code did you use that resulted in you asking this question?

Comment: You ask us to correct your code, but you make it impossible because you don't give your code.

Comment: `Manipulate[ContourPlot[{x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 9}, {x, -14, 14}, {y, -14, 14}, 
  Axes -> True], {a, -3, 3, 1}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, kile! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***"Why did this circle change its contour when it moved?"***

```
Options[ContourPlot, PerformanceGoal]
```

> {PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal}

[`PerformanceGoal >> Properties & Relations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PerformanceGoal.html):

> $PerformanceGoal *is effectively*  ControlActive["Speed", "Quality"]

[`ControlActive >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControlActive.html)

> ControlActive *can be used to switch between a faster computation to be done while controls like sliders are being moved, and a slower computation to be done once the controls are released.*

To override the default setting for `PerformanceGoal` add the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` to `ContourPlot`.

```
Row[{Manipulate[ContourPlot[x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 9, {x, -14, 14}, {y, -14, 14}, 
       Axes -> True, 
       PlotLabel -> Row[{"$PerformanceGoal ->", $PerformanceGoal}]],
    {a, -3, 3, 1}], 
  Manipulate[ContourPlot[x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 9, {x, -14, 14}, {y, -14, 14}, 
       Axes -> True, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
       PlotLabel ->  Row[{"$PerformanceGoal ->", $PerformanceGoal}]], 
   {a, -3, 3, 1}]}]
```

[image]

***"... draw $ax2+bx+c=0$ in the same plane"***

```
Manipulate[Show[ContourPlot[x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 9, {x, -14, 14}, {y, -14, 14}, 
   Frame -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
  Plot[a x^2 + b x + c, {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> 10], Axes -> True], 
  {a, 1, 20, 1}, {b, 1, 20, 1}, {c, -10, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u for your excellent answer. How can add number in the axes there?

    `Manipulate[Plot[a x^2 + b x + c, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 10], {a, 1, 20, 
  1},{b, 1, 20, 1}, {c, -10, 10, 1}]`
 Just like the axes in the code I give above.

Comment: @kile, add the option `Frame -> False` to `ContourPlot[...]`

Comment: Thanks man! You help me a lot! Did u major in Math?